# GCD Dispatched Operation Not Running When App is Placed in Background

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I launch a method that is, essentially, an endless loop using `dispatch_queue_create` and then `dispatch_async` (and then the code-loop is inside the dispatched block).

The loop runs perfectly. However, when the application gets backgrounded, it pauses. Then it restarts when the app takes the foreground.

How can I prevent this from happening? I've been looking [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_create) but it seems that the priority is not one of the things I can choose.

Comment: You want to run an loop infinitely in the background of iOS?

Comment: @pcperini yes, I am polling a queue. I have waits built into the endless loop so I'm not going to drain your iPad battery :)...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter. Unless your app is a phone (Skype) or music player (Spotify), you can't run infinite loops in the background. What you should be doing (as far as Apple is concerned) is using push for data updates.

Comment: @pcperini Problem is that my app (MIDI Designer) processes MIDI input and produces MIDI output. 99% of my users will be looking at the app while they use it, but I have at least one who wants to look at another app instead, on the same iPad. So I want to know what my possibilities are.

Comment: @pcperini also I should note that empirically it works perfectly (but not when app is backgrounded) and it's in the App Store selling now. Neither of these is meaningful, but they may be clues to something.

Comment: I'm with you. Your concerns make sense, but it's just not the way Apple wants things run. You can do whatever you want in the background, but as soon as your user goes to another app you're done (with few exceptions).

Comment: @pcperini it might be legit according to apple. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20 under Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks. Sorry about the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a) method to start a background task. The OS will give you ten minutes and call the expirationHandler block when it ends.

This method will return **UIBackgroundTaskInvalid** if the device can't run code in background  or the task id that you must use to end it otherwise.

You can (and should) end it sooner by calling -[UIApplication endBackgroundTask];

You can probably start a task in the beginning of your block and end it when it ends, if it is a endless loop just start a task in the applicationWillResignActive method and end it on applicationDidBecomeActive. But remember, you only have **ten minutes**, to have more time your app would have to use location, audio, or voip.

Comment: That is amazing (just tried it). So basically I'm getting an extension of 10 minutes and THEN I'm dead in the water? No way around that, right? I think it'll be fine, but just checking...

Comment: Only if you decide to use one of the "Apple approved" background types of tasks. If you play audio your app will be called while in background to provide more audio data, if you need location updates your app will be notified in background, in voip I don't know how it works but it has a bonus, it will start your app with the OS ^^

Comment: Hmmmm... 10 minutes might be enough, because I do not, in fact, play audio. Or perhaps Apple wouldn't mind, since it is a MIDI processing app. So to clarify, if the app uses audio at all, I get infinite backgrounding, or only for audio functions?

Comment: Our app got recused for doing a "little more" than provide audio data to the audio queue in background ^^ but you might be lucky than we were.

Comment: You get infinite backgrounding if your app behaves like the Music app: i.e., music is playing forever until user says "stop".

Comment: @fbernardo so the audio stuff does NOT run the same as this `beginBackgroundTask` which keeps my whole app alive, right? It is actually an audio queue that is kept alive and that is all?

Comment: If I remember correctly yes, but you can enable it and test with and without the beginBackgroundTask. We were doing some calculations on the audio queue callback method and got rejected for it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test empirically, but @pcperini might be right, Apple might not like any abuse of this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Comment: Apple approves app's that use background tasks as I described, but within common sense I think, you can't drain too much battery I suppose. But I think that what you're doing is fine, it's a task that the user will expect to run on background.