# image uploading in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Hi In my app I need to upload multiple images in background by encoding the UIImage into Base64string.Please let me know how to proceed to do the same or advise  me some better way .

Anyways thanks in advance.

Regards
Tapash

Comment: Why are you encoding the images...

Comment: You want to upload images one by one or all at once?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: see EDIT 1

You could just try something like

```
NSArray* images = // Get your images
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(uploadImages:) withObject:images];

...

- (void)uploadImages:(NSArray*)images {
    // Encode images and upload them...
}
```

`performSelectorInBackground:withObject` executes the method in a background thread. The method, in this case `uploadImages:` should be defined in the same class (or delegate to a Util class or similar).

**EDIT 1**

As @user1963877 says, `performSelectorInBackground:withObject` is obsolete and is being gradually replaced by [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html), so **it should not be used anymore**. With `dispatch_async()` you can reproduce the same behavior, as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    // Encode images and upload them, you are in a background thread...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do whatever in UI, you are in UI thread
    }
}
```

Comment: `performSelectorInBackground` is obsolete since GCD was introduced. Better to use `dispatch_async`.

Comment: @user1963877 see my edit and if ok you could undo the downvote

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Please let me know what will happen when my app comes to background at the time of image uploading using GCD.

Comment: You didn't specify in the question that it was the app itself what was going to background, but just the thread. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9812176/1357853

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have implemented. The procedure is given below. I am requesting everyone to modify this if required and proposed more efficient ways:

```
typealias PLMImageUploadCompletionHandler = (AnyObject?, Int, NSError?) -> Void

class ImageUploader: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = ImageUploader()
    private override init() {} //This prevents others from using the default '()' initializer for this class.

    //MARK:- Api Calls
    func uploadImageWithAlamofire(selectedImages: Array<Image> , completionHandler :@escaping PLMImageUploadCompletionHandler)
    {
        //***** Added By Priti ***********////

        let username = "test"
        let password = "XXX122"
        let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)

        let headers:HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Basic \(loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.base64EncodedString())"
        ]

        let imageServiceURl = URL(string:"your url")

        let postParams:[String: Any] = [            
            "fileName":String(describing: fileArray),
            "objectID":String(describing: objectID),
            "comments":String(describing: commentsArray),
            "objectType":String(describing: objectType),
            "uniqueId":String(describing: arrIDs),
            "location":String(describing: locationArray)
        ]

        print(fileArray)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            for (key, value) in postParams
            {
                multipartFormData.append(((value as AnyObject).data(using:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!, withName: key)
            }
            for i in 0..<selectedImages.count {
                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImages[i].value(forKey: "image") as! UIImage,0.6)
                multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: "uploadedFiles", fileName: "image\(i).png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }
        },to:imageServiceURl!, method: .post, headers:headers,
          encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON {
                    response in
                    switch response.result
                    {
                        case.success:
                            print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                            print(response.response!) // URL response
                            print(response.data!)     // server data
                            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                            // Post notification
                            DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                                completionHandler(nil, HttpStatusType.OK_STATUS. rawValue, nil)
                            })
                        break

                        case.failure(let error):
                                completionHandler(nil, HttpStatusType.HTTP_ERROR. rawValue, error as NSError)
                        break
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("error:\(encodingError)")

            }
        })
    } 
}
```